# Could someone please point out the error in my code

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    int p,q,r,s,a[p][q],b[r][s],i,j,k,u,v,res[u][v],sum=0;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of the 1st matrix: ");
    scanf ("%d%d",&p,&q);
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of the 2nd matrix: ");
    scanf ("%d%d",&r,&s);
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix1: ");
    u=p;
    v=s;
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix2: ");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<s;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<s;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<r;k++)
            {
                sum+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
            res[i][j]=sum;
            sum=0;
        }
    }
    printf("The resultant matrix is: ");
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<s;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",res[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

**I'm trying to write a program to perform Matrix Multiplication. The code isn't getting executed...its just terminating and I really cant find the error. When I tried running it online I got ''Bus error(Code Dumped)error 135"...but in my system the programs just terminating without an error. Please help me find the mistake or concept I'm missing here.. **

Comment: out of the `a[p][q],b[r][s]` while sizes are not initialized, you are not protected if an input is not a valid integer or if an enter size is negative etc

Comment: C programs are executed from top to bottom. Therefore the program can't re-visit the declaration `a[p][q]` and fill in the values later, once they are known.

Comment: untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled2.c:5:5: warning: ‘v’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     int p,q,r,s,a[p][q],b[r][s],i,j,k,u,v,res[u][v],sum=0;
     ^~~
untitled2.c:5:5: warning: ‘u’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding, by us humans: 1) please use meaningful variable names rather than: `p` `q` `r` `s` `a` `k` `u` `v`  2) please use appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators. 3) please separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.`  4) please separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: regarding statements like; `scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);`  Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  (the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful input format conversion specifiers (I.E. `%d`)  Suggest: `if( scanf("%d",&a[i][j]) != 1 ) { //handle error }`

Comment: regarding: `'Bus error(Code Dumped)error 135".`  I'd bet that the error message was more like: `"Bus error(Core Dumped)error 135".` Suggest reading: [bus error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error).  We can also be rather sure the error number was not 135 as that is a problem with Adobe, not some program you wrote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code

```
 int p,q,r,s,a[p][q],b[r][s],i,j,k,u,v,res[u][v],sum=0;
```

you are using the values of `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`, `u` and `v` uninitialized. As they have automatic storage (local scope) and the type `int` can have trap representation, and the variables `u` and `v` never have their address taken, it'll invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Even for the other variables other than `u` and `v`, the values will be indeterminate, resulting in practically invalid code.

To resolve the problem, define the VLAs after you scan the values into the respective variables to be used as array dimension.

Comment: without checking the value return by the `scanf` also produce UB if an input is not a valid int because the corresponding vars are used not initialized by the current `scanf`and the next ones

Comment: @bruno I don't think that will be UB, because the address of those variables will be taken. Unspecified and indeterminate - yes.

Comment: `int p, q; scanf ("%d%d",&p,&q); int a[p][q];` has the same UB than `int p, q, int a[p][q]; scanf ("%d%d",&p,&q);` if you enter for instance 'aze' rather than 2 valid int